# "welcoming of someone" vs "welcoming to someone"

Tags: prepositions, difference

Tell me please if can use the preposition *to* after the preposition *welcoming* in the following sentence.

> The Abbasids kept the idea of a hereditary monarchy, but they moved the capital of the empire to Baghdad, and they were much more **welcoming** (**to**) of other non-Arab muslims in positions of power.

This is from [Crash Course World History](https://youtu.be/QV7CanyzhZg). It is at 5 minute and 12 second. The use of the preposition *of* sounds strange to me. I have looked it up the adjective in a few dictionaries, and I have not find the examples of it used with *of*. Would it not be better to use the preposition *to*.

Comment: welcoming of|to = willing to admit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[They are both correct and both commonly used.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=welcoming%20to%2Cwelcoming%20of&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwelcoming%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwelcoming%20of%3B%2Cc0)  Remember that dictionaries give you definitions, but not complete descriptions of how words are used.

This US English speaker actually thinks "welcoming **of**" sounds better - it was certainly more common for most of the last hundred years.  The idea in the sentence is not that the Abbasids gave a specific welcome *to* non-Arab Muslims in positions of power, but that they had a welcoming attitude *about* non-Arab Muslims in positions of power.